# Class 'SoapClient' not found on Google Cloud PHP App

Tags: php, google-app-engine, soap, soap-client

I deployed my php app to Google Cloud and getting currently the following error when i call the line.

```
 $url = "S5WS.wsdl";
 $client = new \SoapClient(dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $url, array('trace' => true, 'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1));
```

**PHP message:**

`PHP Fatal error: Class 'SoapClient' not found in /app/controllers/TicketController.php on line 211`

I opened the terminal in the Google Cloud and typed `php -i | grep -i soap`so to check the status of the soap and it seemds to be fine.

```
baltacii@s5-app-****:/$ php -i | grep -i soap
soap
Soap Client => enabled
Soap Server => enabled
soap.wsdl_cache => 1 => 1
soap.wsdl_cache_dir => /tmp => /tmp
soap.wsdl_cache_enabled => 1 => 1
soap.wsdl_cache_limit => 5 => 5
soap.wsdl_cache_ttl => 86400 => 86400
baltacii@s5-app-167912:/$
```

If i call `phpinfo();` in the app.It returns me in contrast to my localhost no Soap Section. There are only 2 lines related with the soap.

```
SOAP    Brad Lafountain, Shane Caraveo, Dmitry Stogov
```

and in the configure command section

```
'--enable-soap=shared'
```

**EDIT: App runs on PHP Version 5.6**

Answer (score 0):

So according to [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/runtime) some PHP extensions are compiled as shared, but disabled by default.Soap is one of these extensions.In order to activate it. We should create a php.ini in the base folder of the project.

php.ini

```
; Enable the Soap extension
extension=soap.so
```

After new deployment to server soap should be available.